# RadGrid not displayning 0 value when setting GridNumericColumn DataFormatString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

My RadGrid is not displaying a 0 value when setting GridNumericColumn's DataFormatString. How do I show 0 values in a RadGrid GridNumericColumn when I use this code?

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn UniqueName="Discount" DataField="Discount"
    HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
    DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:###,###,###}">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

Comment: Have you tried: DataFormatString="{0:N0}" and have you entered 0 in the cell?

Comment: Is it solved? What was the problem?

Comment: yes. It is solve my problem.

Comment: When I set 0 value in radgrid, it not displayed 0

Comment: But is Currect Now, by this format {0:N0}

Answer (score 1):

Try Using DataFormatString="{0:###,###,##0}" this Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string. SO if Your value is 0 it should display accordingly.